# Add class on scroll change in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I am using this code to add a body class if the user scrolls past a full background image with the id `fullimg`:

```
  jQuery(window).scroll(function() {
  var height = jQuery('#fullimg').offset().top - 70;
  var sticky = jQuery('#fullimg'),
    scroll = jQuery(window).scrollTop();
  if (scroll >= height) sticky.parent('body').addClass('pastimg');
  else sticky.parent('body').removeClass('pastimg');
});
```

However nothing seems to happen.

Comment: `.parent('body').`  why not just `$("body").addClass`?   Are you sure '#fullimg` is a *direct* child of body?   You probably meant `.closest("body")` instead of `.parent` but just `$("body")` will work better

Comment: ok now I can see the class is added but it doesn't get removed by the 'else' condition

Comment: Are you sure the `else` is getting hit?  What *is* the value for `height`?  Add a `console.log(scroll, height)` to see what's happening.   Otherwise, please provide an [mcve] with sample html.